# qt painterpath rotation

Tags: qt, qpainter

I have a circle that drawed with painter path and inside it I have line with the same painter path.I want to rotate the circle but not rotate the line in it?How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the save and restore functions when drawing various parts.

The analog clock is probably close to what you are looking for:

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtgui/analogclock.html

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtgui/analogclock-main-cpp.html